# refresh list view in parent mdi form when close another child form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have  2 forms where 1 parent and 1 child
in my parent form, I have a list view which loaded when form_load

my main_form (mdi parent):

```
void show_list()
{
    string sql = "SELECT * FROM barang";

    list_data.View = View.Details;
    MySqlDataAdapter adap = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    adap.Fill(dt);

    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        DataRow dr = dt.Rows[i];

        ListViewItem listitem = new ListViewItem(dr["ID"].ToString());

        listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["code"].ToString());
        listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["Nama_barang"].ToString());
        listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["Jumlah_barang"].ToString());
        listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["Harga_awal"].ToString());
        listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["Harga_jual"].ToString());

        list_data.Items.Add(listitem);
    } 
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    show_list();
}
```

How I can refresh this form when other form_closed?

Comment: Add an event handler to detect when the child form is closed the call shared code...

Comment: You can handle FormClosed event of your child form.

Comment: Man, undelete the question about the select. I am answering it. I have got an answer for you...